# Order (and enumerate) directory listing by file creation date?

Tags: c#, linq

So I have this routine:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetFiles( string path, string[] searchPatterns, SearchOption searchOption = SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly) {
    return searchPatterns.AsParallel()
                         .SelectMany(searchPattern => 
                             Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, searchPattern, searchOption))
                         .OrderBy<string, string>( (f) => f)
                         .Distinct<string>();
}
```

and its working but ordering the files by its name and I need to order the files returned by its creation date. How can I sort by that if the item is an string like in the routine. I want to use Enumerate cause files are expected to be more than 1k.

Thanks.

Comment: Please simplify/focus the question. Is the question about "Enumerating" or "Ordering"?

Comment: @pst Enumerate files ordered by its creation date

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'm not sure you really want to be using the Task Parallel Library for that query.  For some reasons, see this question [How to find all exe files on disk using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10965280/how-to-find-all-exe-files-on-disk-using-c).

As for enumerating the files by creation date, I would start the function by creating a new [DirectoryInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.aspx) using the path provided, and then call [.EnumerateFiles(string pattern, SearchOption searchOption)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd413343.aspx) to get all the files matching your pattern.  Finally, you can order by the [CreationTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.creationtime.aspx) property of the [FileInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx) objects in the returned enumeration and then either return the full FileInfo objects, or just their [Name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.name.aspx), like so:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetFiles( string path, string[] searchPatterns, SearchOption searchOption = SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly) {
    DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(path);
    var dirs = (from file in dir.EnumerateFiles(searchPatterns, searchOptions)
            orderby file.CreationTime ascending
            select file.Name).Distinct(); // Don't need <string> here, since it's implied
    return dirs;
}
```

Note: I don't have access to a compiler at the moment, but I believe the above code is error free.

Comment: Have to include `using System.Linq;`

Comment: searchOption param, searchOptions in function, serachPattern doesn't like the array

Answer (score 4):

You need to switch to using [DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.enumeratefiles.aspx), which will return a collection of FileInfo instances.  You can then sort these by dates and select out the names.

Answer (score 0):

Examples below:

```
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(path);
//Date created latest first
var files = dir.EnumerateFiles().OrderByDescending(x => x.CreationTime);

//Date created latest last
var files2 = dir.EnumerateFiles().OrderBy(x => x.CreationTime);

//dir.EnumerateFiles() is the same as the ones below
var files3 = dir.EnumerateFiles("*");
var files4 = dir.EnumerateFiles("*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
```